# Using a case statement to assign multiple variable in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm implementing an HSV to RGB function in ruby, and I was hoping for syntax like this:

```
def hsv_to_rgb(h, s, v)
    if (h == 0) then return 0, 0, 0 end
    c = v * s
    hp = h / 60.0
    x = c * (1 - (hp % 2 - 1).abs)
    r, g, b = case hp
        when 0..1
            c, x, 0
        when 1..2
            x, c, 0
        when 2..3
            0, c, x 
        when 3..4
            0, x, c
        when 4..5
            x, 0, c
        else
            c, 0, x
        end

    m = v - c
    return r + m, g + m, b + m
end
```

however, when I attempt to run this in Jruby I get the following error message:

> SyntaxError: julia2.rb:60: syntax error, unexpected '\n'
>                   when 1..2

Does something like this syntax exist in ruby? 
Thanks!

Comment: A few points: 1) You can write write the first line `return 0, 0, 0 if h==0` or `return [0,0,0] if h.zero?`; 2) `(1 - (hp % 2 - 1).abs)` can be simplified to `hp.even? ? 0 : 1`; 3) `when 0..1` is `true` if `hp` equals `0` or `1`, but `when 1..2` is equivalent to `when 2` because `when 0..1` will be executed when `hp` equals `1` (same with remaining `when`'s); 4) the keyword `return` is customarily omitted when it's in the last line of the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your return values in the case statement are not accepted by the ruby engine. I think you want to return an array... using the [] perhaps?

Like this:

```
def hsv_to_rgb(h, s, v)
    if (h == 0) then return 0, 0, 0 end
    c = v * s
    hp = h / 60.0
    x = c * (1 - (hp % 2 - 1).abs)
    r, g, b = case hp
        when 0..1
            [c, x, 0]
        when 1..2
            [x, c, 0]
        when 2..3
            [0, c, x]
        when 3..4
            [0, x, c]
        when 4..5
            [x, 0, c]
        else
            [c, 0, x]
        end

    m = v - c
    return r + m, g + m, b + m
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning array will work and it is more readable as well.